# C program to dynamically allocate memory for structure then memcpy input into

Tags: c

Need some help gurus. I'm new to C, trying to understand how to pull this off.
Ok, so I need to allocate the exact amount of memory for the input NAME(plus a null terminator), and store the pointer to the allocation in its place inside array. Use memcpy to copy NAME into allocated memory, the int values can be stored directly into the corresponding members of the structure in the array element. 
Any help would be appreciated. 
Cheers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ITEMS 5

int main(void)
{
    struct Inventory
    {
        char *name, int year, int amount;
    } brand[ITEMS] = { {"chevy", 2014, 12}, {"acura", 2016, 22} };

    struct Inventory *ptr, s;
    ptr = &s;
    int count, num;

    for (count1 = 0; count < ITEMS; count1++)
    {
        printf("Enter a brand of automobile, year, and count of the vehicle with a space in between:\n");
        scanf("%s%d&d", &ptr->name, &ptr->year, &ptr->amount);

        if ( (ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)) == NULL))
        {
            fputs("Out of memory\n", stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* memcpy */
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", ptr->name, ptr->weight, ptr->calories);
        free(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your compiler not ***Screaming*** warnings at you that might help explain some of your difficulty?

Comment: thanks for your help David, you're swell.

Comment: Please post code that compiles.  You've written `struct Inventory
    {
        char *name, int year, int amount;
    }` which is not valid C — as your compiler should be telling you.  Those commas need to be semicolons.  And you should declare each structure member on its own line.  You should be checking the result of `scanf()`; you should be fixing the format string.  Calling `free(ptr); free(ptr);` is a straight-forward double-free and undefined behaviour.  You aren't making proper use of the allocated memory.  You aren't allocating enough memory.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0):

A structure pointer + an integer:
ptr+count.

Non-initialization of count, using count & incrementing another variable :count1++
for (count1 = 0; count < ITEMS; ++count1)

Rectify these mistakes.

Comment: updating, thanks for the help, its appreciated. Was told to define a structure type, declare, and initialize an array all in one statement, but I'll adjust to at least shut the compiler up.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues that will bite you in your code. While you are free to allocate storage for `name`, that will complicate things quite a bit if you also assign *string literals* to the first 2 elements of `brand`. You then will have mixed literals and allocated blocks of memory that you will have to keep track of in order to know what needs to be freed later on.

Additionally, when using `scanf` to read multiple values, you are better off reading an entire line into a buffer with `fgets` and then calling `sscanf` to parse the values. There are a number of reasons why decoupling your read from your parse makes sense.

Also, if name is short, then why not use an array and eliminate the dynamic allocation altogether? For purposes of your example, where you are assigning literals to the first two, that also solves your problem of which will need to be `free`d and which will *segfault* if you try to free them.

I've included more in the comments below. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { ITEMS = 5, MAXN = 32, MAXC = 256 };

typedef struct {
    char name[MAXN];
    int year, amount;
} inventory;

int main (void) {

    /* you do not want to mix string literals below for 'name' with allocated
     * blocks of memory also used for 'name' because the logic to free the allocated
     * blocks would be unnecessarily complicated. (e.g., some 'name's allocated,
     * some holding literals) Keep your code consistent. If the length of name is
     * reasonably short, just use an array.
     */
    inventory brand[ITEMS] = { {"chevy", 2014, 12}, {"acura", 2016, 22} };
    int num = 2;

    while (num < ITEMS) {

        char buf[MAXC] = "";
        /* no need for ptr, it's up to you, brand[num] with dot notation is fine */
        inventory *ptr = &brand[num];
        printf ("Enter a brand of automobile, year, and count "
                "of the vehicle with a space in between:\n");
        /* if name is a pointer, you must allocate space before calling scanf
         * (unless using the 'm' modifier ('a' for older scanf and windoze) and
         * you then provide a pointer-to-pointer-to-char) Using an array avoids
         * that problem wit name.
         */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) ||
            sscanf (buf, " %s %d %d", ptr->name, &ptr->year, &ptr->amount) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            continue;
        }

        /* allocating 1-char for ptr is somewhat pointless here */
        // if ( !(ptr = malloc (sizeof(char)) == NULL)) {
        /* you would allocate the sizeof one struct, or just s, however using
         * an array for name makes allocation unnecessary.
         */
        // if (!(ptr = malloc (sizeof s))) {
        //     fputs ("Out of memory", stderr);  /* fputs adds a newline */
        //     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        // }

        /* memcpy -- WTF?? (there is no memcpy here, what is weight, calories?) */
        // printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", ptr->name, ptr->weight, ptr->calories);

        /* you probably want */

        // free(ptr); (no allocation, no free required
        num++;
    }

    /* now lets see if it worked */
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf ("\n name   : %s\n year   : %d\n amount : %d\n",
                brand[i].name, brand[i].year, brand[i].amount);

    return 0;
}
```

(lastly, leave *MixedCase* variable names for C++. C style generally prefers all lower-case, reserving upper-case for constants and macros. While style is completely up to you, an odd style telegraphs a lot about your code before any of the details are reached)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inventory2
Enter a brand of automobile, year, and count of the vehicle with a space in between:
ford 1968 7
Enter a brand of automobile, year, and count of the vehicle with a space in between:
foo bar
error: invalid input.
Enter a brand of automobile, year, and count of the vehicle with a space in between:
mazda 2007 9
Enter a brand of automobile, year, and count of the vehicle with a space in between:
toyota 2012 4

 name   : chevy
 year   : 2014
 amount : 12

 name   : acura
 year   : 2016
 amount : 22

 name   : ford
 year   : 1968
 amount : 7

 name   : mazda
 year   : 2007
 amount : 9

 name   : toyota
 year   : 2012
 amount : 4
```